# how to do make a flex-column inside a flex-item row?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a board layout where each column contains a title, flex-item, and sub-items on hover event, but however, when I tried to make a column on the second column this takes all the screen. how can I fix this error? I want to place a few columns and the items as per adding , in this case column , and row to look like the images [image: error]

[image: layout]

code

```
<style>
        .flex-container {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      max-height:600px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
    
      -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .flex-item {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .ex-col {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 420px;
      background: white;
      padding: 20px;
      color: #555;
    }
    
    .ex-col h2 {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      line-height: 1.3em;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0 0 10px;
      padding: 0 0 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid slategray;
      width: 100%;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .ex-col h2>small {
      display: block;
      font-size: .9rem;
      line-height: 1.3rem;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    .ex-list {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    
    
    /* The list item element. Must be FLEX */
    
    .ex-list>li {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 70px;
    }
    
    
    /* The list heading element */
    
    .ex-list h3 {
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      padding: 6px 8px;
      border: 1px solid slategray;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      /*  Set flex size to 50% of the parent element width. 
          This is a good way to make sure it is always 50% */
      flex-basis: 100%;
      max-width: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .ex-list h3>small {
      font-size: .6em;
      line-height: 1em;
      color: lightgray;
      margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
    }
    
    
    /* The sub-menu element. Initial state is display:none */
    
    .ex-list-sub {
      display: none;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0 0 0 20px;
      margin: 0;
      position: relative;
      flex-basis: 100%;
      max-width: 50%;
      transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-left: none;
    }
    
    .ex-list-sub:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 20px;
      background: gray;
    }
    
    .ex-list-sub>li:not(:first-child) {
      border-top: 1px solid gray;
    }
    
    .ex-list-sub>li>a {
      display: block;
      padding: 6px 8px;
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: background .2s;
    }
    
    .ex-list-sub>li>a:hover {
      background: #efefef;
    }
    
    
    /* THE HOVER ACTION */
    
    
    /*  Set the hover on the parent element. 
        Has to be the parent because otherwise the pop-up would disappear when you hover over it */
    
    .ex-list>li:hover .ex-list-sub {
      display: block;}
    </style>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="ex-col">
          <h2>
            Reconnaissance
            <small>10 Techniques</small>
          </h2>
          <ul class="ex-list">
            <li>
              <h3>
                Active Scanning
                <small>(0/2)</small>
              </h3>
              <ul class="ex-list-sub">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    Scanning IP Blocks
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    Vulnerability Scanning
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ex-col">
          <h2>
            Reconnaissance
            <small>10 Techniques</small>
          </h2>
          <ul class="ex-list">
            <li>
              <h3>
                Active Scanning
                <small>(0/2)</small>
              </h3>
              <ul class="ex-list-sub">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    Scanning IP Blocks
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    Vulnerability Scanning
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it's unclear what you want.  can you show a complete diagram?

Comment: I want to remove the margin from the code and make it look like columns followed each flex-item

Comment: still not clear.

Comment: i want to remove the margin , and make them as columns